# Moving MSSQL Express 2008 R2 to new laptop (and Coldfusion DSNs)

Tags: coldfusion, sql-server-express

My old laptop is going bye bye so I need to move my sql configuration to the new laptop.  I'd like to move the user accounts, too.  I've googled the topic but I'm only finding how to move the databases over which I've got that done, I need to get the user accounts now.  Any help would be appreciated.

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2
Coldfusion 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Google'd you should have come across this article from Microsoft:

[How to transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992)

...and countless others.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It proved to be helpful more than your additional commentary, "...and countless others."

Comment: If your question can be answered by clicking the first result in Google, perhaps you should try there first :)